# Toyota 4 Runner starting question

Tags: engine, 4runner

My husband has a 2003 4 Runner. He tells me that it causes excessive wear to the engine to start the car and move it to a different spot in the driveway once or twice in a day, without driving it. I sometimes request for him to move it so I have access to my car and don't have to drive the other clunker in the driveway. Is he correct in that starting his car to move it is damaging his car, and I should respect that? Or is he exaggerating and just doesn't want me to move his car? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Your husband is full of baloney. Once or twice a day is inconsequential unless you have a weak battery that needs replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a car for 30 seconds to move it once is fine, but to do that several times a day every day will accelerate wear and may also lead to a flat battery since it does not have time to re-charge...

We used to say a battery would need 7 to 10 miles of "good" driving - not idling in traffic to get charged...

Can you plan the parking of an evening so the cars are in the "correct" order for the morning...